# Comparison of words in a string?

Tags: c, string, function, char, comparator

Is there a function which I can use to compare strings where the position of the words would not matter? I mean that "Aaron Jack Brussels" is the same as "Brussels Aaron Jack" etc.

Comment: That seems like a very specific issue, so I highly doubt there is. You could try splitting each word into a list and then compare if each list has the same elements.

Comment: There is no standard library function for this.

Comment: Probably yes, I have a similar idea, I just wanted to ask if anyone will come up with something better :)

Comment: aaron18, Post your solution and ask for something better.  Sure to get many ideas.

Comment: Sort the word list and compare.

Comment: many potential criteria possible for example how to treat duplicates. Not enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard function that will do anything close to your goal. You need to write specific code. You can iterate on one string and search for each word in the other string and vice versa.

Here is a simple implementation that does not modify the strings nor allocate any memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countword(const char *w, size_t len, const char *str) {
    size_t i;
    int count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        while (*str == ' ')
            str++;
        if (!*str)
            return count;
        for (i = 1; str[i] && str[i] != ' '; i++)
            continue;
        if (i == len && !memcmp(w, str, len))
            count++;
        str += i;
    }
}

int samewords(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const char *p0, *p;

    for (p = s1;;) {
        while (*p == ' ')
            p++;
        if (!*p)
            return 1;
        for (p0 = p++; *p && *p != ' '; p++)
            continue;
        if (countword(p0, p - p0, s1) != countword(p0, p - p0, s2))
            return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    if (samewords("Aaron  Jack  Brussels", "Brussels Aaron Jack"))
        printf("OK\n");
    if (samewords("Aaron  Jack  Brussels", "AaronJackBrussels"))
        printf("Not OK\n");
    if (samewords("Aaron Jack", "Aaron Jack Jack"))
        printf("Not OK\n");
    if (samewords("Aaron Jack Brussels", "Aaron Jack"))
        printf("Not OK\n");
    if (samewords("John John Doe", "John Doe Doe"))
        printf("Not OK\n");    return 0;
}
```

You can extend it to handle multiple separators such as space, TAB and newline using `strspn()` and `strcspn()` from `<string.h>`:

```
int countword(const char *w, size_t len, const char *str) {
    const char *separators = " \t\r\n";
    size_t i;
    int count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        str += strspn(str, separators);
        if (!*str)
            return count;
        i = strcspn(str, separators);
        if (i == len && !memcmp(w, str, len))
            count++;
        str += i;
    }
}

int samewords(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const char *separators = " \t\r\n";
    const char *p0, *p;

    for (p = s1;;) {
        p += strspn(p, separators);
        if (!*p)
            return 1;
        p += strcspn(p0 = p, separators);
        if (countword(p0, p - p0, s1) != countword(p0, p - p0, s2))
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Note: I updated the answer with a more general version that can handle duplicated words such as `"John John Doe"` <-> `"John Doe Doe"` which the previous version would have mistakenly considered equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can use a combination of `strtok()` (or its more useful reentrant cousin `strtok_r()`) to split your strings by a " " delimiter, and `strcmp()` to compare each substring against all other substrings.

My example is pretty crude (it assumes same number of substrings in both string sets, and also only checks one set against the other set), but should serve to put you on the right track.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  char stringA[] = "Aaron Jack Brussels";
  char stringB[] = "Brussels Aaron Jack";                                                           
  int numSubStrings = 3;

  char **stringSetA, **stringSetB;
  char *saveStrA, *saveStrB;

  stringSetA = malloc(numSubStrings*sizeof(*stringSetA));
  stringSetB = malloc(numSubStrings*sizeof(*stringSetB));

  // extract first token of each to initialize strtok
  stringSetA[0] = strtok_r(stringA, " ", &saveStrA);
  stringSetB[0] = strtok_r(stringB, " ", &saveStrB);

  // loop through the string to extract all other tokens                                            
  for (int i = 1; i < numSubStrings; ++i) {
    stringSetA[i] = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveStrA);
    stringSetB[i] = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveStrB);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numSubStrings; ++i) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < numSubStrings; ++j) {
      // strcmp == 0 if both strings are equal                                                      
      if (!strcmp(stringSetA[i], stringSetB[j])) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) printf("Both sets of strings aren't equal!\n");
    else printf("Found %s!\n", stringSetA[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stringSetA = malloc(numSubStrings*sizeof(char*));` -> `stringSetA = malloc(numSubStrings*sizeof *stringSetA);`

Comment: Also, you should change `while` to `for` and move declaration of `i` inside the for headers.

Comment: Why the suggested change in the first comment? They are both functionally equal, your edit obscures the type for the reader.

Comment: You should not assume that both strings have 3 words, furthermore this code will erroneously consider `"A A A"` to be equivalent to `"A B C"`.

Comment: "My example is pretty crude (it assumes same number of substrings in both string sets, and also only checks one set against the other set), but should serve to put you on the right track."

Comment: It removes some code duplication. Why do you want to repeat the type?

Comment: The only reason you're supplying the sizeof in the first place is because C is to stupid to figure it out on its own :)

Comment: > It removes some code duplication. Fair enough, I figured I would make the `malloc()`s as verbose as possible for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @JacobFaib If you in the future decide to change it to a version with `wchar_t`, will you remember to also change all the calls to `malloc`?

Comment: @JacobFaib *Why the suggested change in the first comment? They are both functionally equal, your edit obscures the type for the reader.* Beyond klutt's comments, there's also a fundamental reason why using the variable name in the `sizeof()` is better than the type, beyond code duplication:  using the type directly creates an unlinked (and likely undocumented) dependency in your code.  By "unlinked" I mean there's no way to depend on your tools to identify the dependency and keep it correct.  And if you document it with a comment, that comment's content is then an unlinked dependency.

Comment: (cont) That's a more general problem than just code duplication.  Unlinked, undocumented dependencies cause all kinds of problems when trying to get code working, and they make trying to keep it working when changes are necessary even harder.  In general, any code of any type that falls into, "If I change this here, that waaay over there breaks, and there's not even a compiler warning much less an error" is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really doing is creating two sets (the mathematical ones) of strings, and trying to compare those sets. Unfortunately, an unsorted array (such as a string) is not conducive to this comparison. Looking on github for C libraries that implement a set might be a better place to start (I think https://github.com/barrust/set would suit your needs).

If you really need a naive implementation, this should work and avoids allocations or string modification:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

enum cmp_result { CMP_EQV, CMP_NEQV, CMP_SUB, CMP_SUPER };

bool is_word_subset(const char *s1, const char *s2);
enum cmp_result cmp_wordset(const char *s1, const char *s2);
const char *get_word_end(const char *s);

enum cmp_result cmp_wordset(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{

    enum cmp_result res1, res2;

    res1 = is_word_subset(s1, s2) ? CMP_SUB : CMP_NEQV;
    res2 = is_word_subset(s2, s1) ? CMP_SUB : CMP_NEQV;

    if ( res1 == CMP_SUB && res2 == CMP_SUB) {
        return CMP_EQV;
    }
    else if ( res1 == CMP_SUB ) {
        return CMP_SUB;
    }
    else if ( res2 == CMP_SUB ) {
        return CMP_SUPER;
    }
    else {
        return CMP_NEQV;
    }
}

// checks if every word in s1 is also in s2
bool is_word_subset(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const char *start1, *end1, *start2, *end2;
    size_t len1, len2;
    
    start1 = s1;
    do {
        end1 = get_word_end(start1);
        
        start2 = s2;
        do {
            end2 = get_word_end(start2);
            
            len1 = end1 - start1;
            len2 = end2 - start2;
            
            // compares the two current words. memcmp returns 0 on equal strings
            // if there is a match, then the given word in s1 is also in s2, and
            // we can return to the outer loop to get the next word
            if ( len1 == len2 && !memcmp(start1, start2, len1) ) { 
                start1 = end1 + 1;
                goto out;
            }
            start2 = end2 + 1; // update start2 to point to the next word in s2
        } while ( *end2 );
        
        // if there is a word in s1 that is not in s2, then the
        // inner loop will exit without breaking. In this case, s1 is not
        // a subset of s2, and so we return false.
        return false;
        out: 0;
        start1 = end1 + 1; // update start1 to point to the next word in s1
    } while ( *end1 );

    return true;
}

// gets the character following the current word.
// for all words but the last one in the string,
// this character will be a space.
const char *get_word_end(const char *s) {
    const char *end;
    
    end = strchr(s, ' ');
    if ( !end ) {
        end = s + strlen(s);
    }
    
    return end;
}
```